# How I get computed column in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables.

One is the `PRODUCT` table and it has `unitSalePrice` and other table is `ORDERPRODUCT` and it has a column `productQuantity` (how much order from particular product) and also `ORDERS` to add detail of customer's orders.

I wrote a `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    ORDERPRICE 
FROM
    PRODUCT, ORDERPRODUCT, ORDERS
WHERE 
    ORDERPRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID 
    AND ORDERS.ORDER_ID = ORDERPRODUCT.ORDER_ID
    AND ORDERPRICE AS (ORDERPRODUCT.PRODUCTQTY * PRODUCT.UNITSALEPRICE) ;
```

but this `ORDERPRICE` column is not in those 3 tables and it is dummy column.

When I run this query it gives error column is not exists.

How do I do this???

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn to use explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT (op.PRODUCTQTY * p.UNITSALEPRICE) AS ORDERPRICE
FROM PRODUCT p JOIN
     ORDERPRODUCT op
     ON op.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON o.ORDER_ID = op.ORDER_ID;
```